Unable to list all kafka brokers on zookeeper host
I have setup 3 zookeeper + 5 brokers. However when I try to list all brokers on one zookeeper host, it only return two brokers id.
I run below command on zookeeper host:
`> /opt/kafka/current/bin/zookeeper-shell.sh localhost:2181

ls /brokers/ids
[111, 112]`

expect:
return all 5 brokers ids
Any of your help is much appreciated, many thanks

Are the other 3 brokers actively running and healthy?
